# How to track a kidnapper's phone

Tags: technology, espionage

I'm writing a novel, in which one of my characters is kidnapped. Fortunately for her, her kidnappers aren't extremely good at the whole kidnapping thing. She manages to gain access to one of their phones, and also finds an opportunity to escape.

Here's her predicament. For various reasons (plot stuff :-), she doesn't want to call the cops just yet. But she DOES want to get away, and she DOES want to track her kidnappers so that she knows where they go next. Is there a way for her to install some kind of app or something in the kidnapper's phone that can enable her to track it undetected? I know there are spy apps out there, but not sure if it's feasible to download anything in her situation.

Update: Also...she does not have her own phone with her. The kidnappers were smart enough to destroy it.

Comment: That totally depends on whether she knows, where she can find the tool she needs on the internet. I.e. without her either being a computer security researcher, hacker, detective, stalker, or secret service agent, her chances are next to nonexistent.

Comment: There have been several "stealth" tracking apps marketed as designed for parents to be be able to keep track of their kids.  These are designed to not be obvious and not easily removed by the user to prevent teenagers from just removing them doing whatever they like.  The are mainstream enough you could get one straight from the phone's app store. As a kid, she would be likely to know about these since her and or her friends would probably be aware of having one on their phone(s)

Comment: There are countless applications which basically send the position of a phone periodically to one or more recipients. Glympse is an example, or search for family GPS tracking.

Comment: People have voted to close (not me) because this is story-plot-based not world-building.  It might be worth your while removing the story element and framing a straightforward  technical question to a different forum. P.S. I'm sure there is spyware out there that people use to check on their spouse/partner when suspected of cheating - just search for it!

Comment: @chasly-reinstateMonica, thanks for the comment! Totally understand this question getting closed...I didn't consider the "story-plot-based" issue. I did some research, but just wanted make sure I wasn't missing something. The responses were still very helpful. Best wishes :-)

Answer (score 4):

**Easier would be to use her own phone.**

In the scene where she gets hold of her phone, she initially is going to call the cops.  But then she gets a different idea - she sets the phone on Do Not Disturb,  plugs her phone into a charger in the back seat of the car and wedges it between the seats.

The kidnapper might notice something is up with his own phone, or turn it off.  No-one is looking for her phone.  It will not ring.  It will stay charged unless someone unplugs it.  She can track it from her home computer.

Comment: Cool idea, thanks :-) But the kidnappers actually destroyed her phone. I should've mentioned this. I'll update my question to include that information.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is very simple. I would frame it as this:

Your protagonist has tracker app installed on her own phone, so that if someone robbed her phone she could track it, block it, etc. This way, you explain *why* she is already familiar with that app. She would have investigated the available apps months ago when she bought her expensive phone (or she was recommended it by someone else). Clearly, you wouldn't want to spend some precious minutes looking at dozens available apps in the market rather than escaping.

When she gets hold of the phone, she opens the market and installs the same app she has on her own phone (she knows its name, so she goes directly to that), and logs in with the credentials of her online account (so that the kidnapper's phone gets linked to her account, and she can thus spy as she would with her own phone). It can be done very quickly.

As you are making up the spy app, you can also decide which features it offers, but showing an innocuous looking icon and name so that it passes as something else (when the robber looks at it) is not an uncommon one. Your kidnappers probably have lots and lots of apps installed, so they don't notice a new one.

So, focusing on your questions:

> Is there a way for her to install some kind of app or something in the kidnapper's phone that can enable her to track it undetected?

Yes

> I know there are spy apps out there, but not sure if it's feasible to download anything in her situation.

It would be feasible. I think the hard part is to explain *how* they left their phone unattended so that their victim could grab it, and how she could access it.

Note that letting her grab even a locked phone would be critical for a kidnapper, since an emergency call doesn't require unlocking the phone.

I would make it so that the kidnapper used the phone in front of her and she could the used passcode to unlock it (maybe the kidnapper complained that it is not recognizing their fingerprint? Or it would usually use FaceID to unlock their phone, but now they are wearing a ski mask in front of her?). The passcode could be a series of points that make a letter (which she later finds it's the kidnapper's initial), or maybe their birth year (or that of a child).

Once she is able to get the passcode to unlock the phone, installing an app would be no trouble. (Realistically, she'd better call/message the cops, but maybe she was not be thinking clearly...)